# Software to ping nodes

Tags: linux, windows, cacti

I'm looking for a similar tool to Cacti and Multiping inn the image, it can be for linux or for windows. I need to pool 1000+ nodes 1 time every second. Any one got a suggestion to what software i can use?
ping 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I like [Ping Monitor](http://emcosoftware.com/ping-monitor) if you're looking for a free version. If you have a budget to work with the [Solarwinds Engineer's Toolset](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/toolsets/engineer.aspx) has all kinds of awesome ping goodies.

EDIT: Nevermind on the freeware version of Ping Monitor, it's restricted to 5 nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a GUI?  I've just started experimenting with Observium and fping.  fping is an older tool, but it allows for simultaneous pings and is used by Observium behind the scenes.  Observium also supports increasing a number of concurrent pollers to increase performance.  It's a full fledged monitoring system though, so pollers are going to do a lot more than just pings (SNMP operations, etc).

The website is http://www.observium.org

and the page on optimization is at observium.org /wiki/Performance_tuning

If you don't need a GUI you could just fork a couple of fpings, depending on it's underlying design.

I know it looks a little sketchy, but I've used http://fping.sourceforge.net/ without a problem.  The project has moved around, so the actual package is now on SourceForge.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [pinger](http://aa.vslib.cz/silk/projekty/pinger/index.php)? It's a unix tool, but should probably work under cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [angry IP.](http://www.angryip.org/w/Home)

It has both linux and windows versions.